# about finite group and maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

prove : let $G$ be a finite group and any two maximal subgroups are conjugate then $G$ is cyclic .also can we say $|G|=p^n$ for  prime number $p$ ?

If $G$ has only one conjugacy class of maximal subgroup, $M$, and is not itself a $p$-group, then for every prime $p$, $M$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$.  But then by Lagrange, $|M|$ has order divisible by every prime power dividing $|G|$, so $|M|$ is a multiple of $|G|$.  Since $|M| \leq |G|$, one must have $|M| = |G|$ and $M = G$, a contradiction.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @DerekHolt.I can't understand why  for every prime $p$, $M$ contains a Sylow p-subgroup $P$ of $G$ ?

Comment: "$|M|$ has order divisible by every prime power dividing $|G|$, so $|M|$ is a mutliple of $|G|$" where did that come from?

Comment: @amirbahadory $M$ contains a Sylow $p$-subgroup because all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate. And so one of the conjugates has to fall in $M$ by our assumption that all maximal subgroups conjugate.

Comment: Every Sylow $p$-subgroup is contained in some maximal subgroup of $G$, and since all maximal subgroups have the same order, your statement follows.

Comment: @freakish isn't the statement that you asked about obvious?

Comment: @DerekHolt not to me. What am I missing?

Comment: If  $|G| = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$ with the $p_i$ distinct primes, and each $p_i^{a_i}$ divides $|M|$, then $|G|$ must divide $|M|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, I guess that "$|G|$ must divide $|M|$" is a bit misleading to me. They are simply equal. But yeah, that's fine, thanks.

Comment: It's really weird, but someone else seems to have just asked that question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601886/