# If each member of a set of distinct primes divides $a$, then their product divides $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $X$ be a set of $m$ distinct primes and $a$ a strictly positive integer. For each $p\in X$, let $a\in p^{i_p}\mathbb{Z}$ where $i_p$ is a strictly positive integer. Does it follow that $a\in\prod_{p\in X}p^{i_p}\mathbb{Z}$?

I have tried to prove this using induction on $|X|$ with the base case $n=1$. Assume it holds for some $n\geq1$. Let $|X|=n+1$. Then $X$ is nonempty: let $p\in X$. Thus $a\in p^{i_p}\mathbb{Z}$ and $$a\in \prod_{q\in X-\{p\}}q^{i_q}\mathbb{Z}.$$ 
I am stuck at this point. I am not sure what I should try to do next.

Comment: For $a \in p^{i_p}\mathbb{Z} $ you mean there exists a integer $i_p$ and an integer $n_p$ such that $a=p^{i_p}n_p$?

Comment: Yes, $p^{i_p}$ divides a.

Comment: Can't you just say that, by the definition of prime, $p_i^{i_{p_i}}  \not| p_j^{j_{p_j}}$ for distinct $i,j$? So for instance, starting from $a=p_1^{i_{p_1}}n_1$ you have that, since $p_2 | a$, $p_2 \not| p_1 \implies p_2 | n_1$, so that $a =p_1^{i_{p_1}}p_2^{i_{p_2}}n_2 $ and so on..

Answer (score 1):

Induction works fine if you generalize the assertion suitably:

> If $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$ are pairwise co-prime divisors of $a$, then also their product $p_1\dotsb p_n$ divides $a$.

The base case $n=2$ is easy. Assuming $n\ge 3$, by the induction hypothesis, we have  $p_1\dotsb p_{n-1}\mid a$; but also $p_n\mid a$ and $\gcd(p_1\dotsb p_{n-1},p_n)=1$; consequently, applying the base case assertion, $p_1\dotsb p_{n-1}\cdot p_n\mid a$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{p_1, ... ,p_t\}$ In the prime decomposition of $a$, each member of $X$ must appear to a positive power. Let the prime decomposition of $a$ be
 $$a=p_1^{i_1}...p_t^{i_t}q_1^{j_1}...q_u^{j_u} \text { where }i_1,...,i_t,j_1,...,j_u \ge 1.$$ Let $$b=p_1...p_t.$$ Then $$b=p_1^1...p_t^1q_1^0...q_u^0$$ Since for each prime $p$ in the prime decompositions of $a$ and $b$, the power to which $p$ appears in $b$ is less than or equal to the power to which $p$ appears in $a$, $b$ divides $a.$